# Need to remove border between cells in UITableView when using background image in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having trouble removing the white border that appears between each cell inside my `UITableView`.  I have tried using:

```
[myTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

inside my `viewDidLoad` method, but unfortunately that does not seem to work.  I am using a background image for my cells to display, and it is the border between these images that I wish to remove.  The image itself is the size of each cell, and the size of each cell I set in my `CustomTableViewCell` class as follows:

```
self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);
```

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mycell";

    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    cell.ID.text = [[DataModel sharedInstance].ID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.Name.text = [[DataModel sharedInstance].Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.Date.text = [[DataModel sharedInstance].Date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cell.png"]]];


    return cell;
}
```

Despite everything I have done, I am seeing a clear white border between my cells in the table.  I really would like to remove this.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: Is this a grouped tableview?

Comment: Thanks to your prompt replies.  @johan:  I tried that line inside my viewDidLoad method, and I am getting the same result.

Comment: @MishieMoo, my table is not grouped.

Comment: I am wondering if I should explicitly set the borders of my background image?

Comment: I had the same issue a few weeks ago and couldn't work it out.

Comment: Are you using interface builder/storyboard?

Comment: Is your row height matching the cell height - `UITableView.rowHeight`?

Comment: @Till:  How can I check to see if they are?

Comment: NSLog, lldb> po, enforcing them to match, .... Ok, seriously; `self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.0f;` in viewDidLoad. I chose 80 as you seem to intend that to be your cell content height.

Comment: @Till:  I tried your suggestion, and unfortunately that only enlarged the height of the rows for some reason, with the white border remaining unchanged.

Comment: This can be done in Interface Builder - see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Interface Builder - change the separator to None and then the separator color to clear color:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting UITableView separatorColor at viewDidLoad might be too early. Try viewWillAppear instead.